# How can I random seed a MySQL column?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, random, sql-update

The column in my database contains 4 statuses:

- 0-Active
- 1-Awaiting User input
- 2-Archive In Progress
- 3-Excluded From Archival

I need to go through the column and randomly change things that are not marked as 0 to some random picking of the other 3 statuses.

What would be the best way for me to go about this? It was requested I use a Python script with random seed so that the state could be recreated. Does anyone have thoughts?

Comment: You would very well do this with a pure MySQL query. Why do you specifically want to use python for this?

Comment: @GMB That's what I was thinking as well. My manager just requested I use a Python script to recreate it quickly. I'll go ahead and look into the MySQL route as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the point using python here, you can adress the very same requirement with a pure MySQL query, like so:

```
update mytable set mystatus = floor(1 + rand() * 3) where mystatus <> 0
```

For each row, expression `floor(1 + rand() * 3)` gives you a random value between 1 and 3.

As for the seed, [the documentation says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> If an integer argument `N` is specified, it is used as the seed value:
>
> - With a constant initializer argument, the seed is initialized once when the statement is prepared, prior to execution.
> - With a nonconstant initializer argument (such as a column name), the seed is initialized with the value for each invocation of  `RAND()`.
>
> One implication of this behavior is that for equal argument values, `RAND(N)` returns the same value each time, and thus produces a repeatable sequence of column values.